# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UserRegistrationComponent -> FormBuilder]:

Tags: angular

when I click on the link **routerLink="user/registration"**:

the form should appear **src/app/user/user-registration.component.html** but an error appears in the console:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UserRegistrationComponent -> FormBuilder]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[UserRegistrationComponent -> FormBuilder]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for FormBuilder!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UserRegistrationComponent -> FormBuilder]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[UserRegistrationComponent -> FormBuilder]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for FormBuilder!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:1002)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1110)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1110)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10854)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12087)
    at resolveDep (core.js:12577)
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:1002)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1110)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1110)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10854)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12087)
    at resolveDep (core.js:12577)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:775)
    at eval (zone.js:858)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4740)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1517)
```

The link is placed in the component **src/app/core/menu/menu.component.html**

```
<ul>         
    <li>
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="user/registration">Rejestracja</a>
    </li>         
</ul>
```

The core module contains **src/app/core/core.module.html**:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  declarations: [MenuComponent],
  exports: [MenuComponent ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

**src/user/user.module.ts** contains the code:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: 'user/registration',
    component: UserRegistrationComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    UserRegistrationComponent
  ],
  exports: [UserRegistrationComponent, FormsModule]
})
export class UserModule { }
```

**app.module.ts** contains the code:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
    path: '',
    component: MenuComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    CoreModule,
    UserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I don't know what the error caused is.

Comment: Are you using the `FormBuilder` in your user-registration.component.ts? That comes from the ReactiveFormsModule, not the FormModule.

Comment: Yes, I'm using FormBuilder. I corrected I added to user.module.ts imports: [// ... ReactiveFormsModule] but now such an error appears:  
     Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UserRegistrationComponent -> AuthService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[UserRegistrationComponent -> AuthService]:

Comment: That is because your AuthService isn't in the providers array in the app.module. ALL of your services will need to be in there if you want to use them via injection. This is basic Angular.

Comment: I still have this error `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AuthService -> Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AuthService -> Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!`

Comment: You need to add the HttpModule into the imports array in the appropriate module, likely the app.module. That means you will need to import it there too. Without that none of the http calls will work.

Comment: @R. Richards many thanks. It works

Answer (score 1):

In your UserModule

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule, // -> this registers the formbuilder service for your module
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    UserRegistrationComponent
  ]
})
export class UserModule { }
```

You don't need to declare exports unless it is a shared module and you wanna use the UserRegistrationComponent outside of the UserModule within a template.